# Integral over the hypersphere

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

Assume I have a *diagonal* matrix $L$ of size $n$. I want to compute the following integral:
$$I_n(L) \equiv \int_{(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})^2} \mathrm{d}\sigma(x)  \mathrm{d}\sigma(x') \exp[n x^\top L \, x']$$
In which $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $ \mathrm{d}\sigma$ is the usual measure on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, with $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \mathrm{d}\sigma(x) = 2 \pi^{n/2}/\Gamma(n/2)$.
I am looking for either a general form of $I_n(L)$ or simply an asymptotic of $\frac{1}{n}\log I_n(L)$ as $n \to \infty$.

I tried but could not find such results. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Looks a bit hairy. The only case I can do is that of $n=2$ when the modified Bessel function $I_0$ pops out. Then again, I suck at integrals.

Comment: Maybe brute force using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates :D

Comment: I didn't manage brute force with hyper-spherical coordinates...

Comment: The integral is invariant to rotation, and so you may have some luck changing variables. If you take a look in the book "Multivariate Statistics: A vector space approach" by Morris L Eaton. It gives some really nice invariance theorems, and proofs about the Wishart distribution. It might take a little bit of work.

Comment: Does the dimension $n$ of the matrix $L$ is the same as the parameter $n$ in the exponential ? In which case, an asymptotic of $\frac1{n}\log I_n(L)$ would depend on a sequence of diagonal matrices $L_n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to get an infinite series using the expansion of $\exp$, however, it may be more efficient to compute the result using quadrature. The steps below first expand $\exp$, and use the multinomial theorem to get a polynomial expansion for the integrand. Taking the integral inside the sum to the monomials we can evaluate the integral directly to obtain an analytic (closed form) expression for the integral.

For clarity, first denote the integral by $I$, i.e.
\begin{align}
  I := \int_{S_n}\int_{S_n}\exp(n \textbf{x}^T L \textbf{y}) d\sigma_n d\sigma_n
\end{align}

**Power series for exp**

If we first consider the expansion of the function argument in the integral,
\begin{align}
  \exp(n \textbf{x}^T L \textbf{y}) =& \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n\textbf{x}^T L \textbf{y})^k}{k!} \\
 =& \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(n \sum_{r=1}^M x_r L_{rr}y_r \right)^k}{k!} \tag{1}
\end{align}

It is well known that the series converges uniformly, and the spherical integral is linear (see [1]), which means we can take the integrals inside the summation,

\begin{align}
  I = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!} \int_{S_n}\int_{S_n}\left( \sum_{r=1}^M x_r L_{rr}y_r \right)^kd\sigma_n d\sigma_n \tag{2}
\end{align}

**Use of the multinomial theorem**

Using the multinomial theorem on the inner bracket gives,
\begin{align}
\left( \sum_{r=1}^M x_r L_{rr}y_r \right)^k =& \sum_{j_{1} + \ldots + j_{M} = k} \frac{k!}{j_{1}!\ldots j_{M}!} \prod_{t=1}^M (L_{tt} y_t x_t)^{j_t} \tag{3}
\end{align}

We can then put (3) into (2) and distribute the integrals further over the addition to give,

\begin{align}
  I = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!}\sum_{j_{1} + \ldots + j_{M} = k} \rho_k \int_{S_n}\int_{S_n} \prod_{t=1}^M (L_{tt} y_t x_t)^{j_{t}}d\sigma_n d\sigma_n \tag{4}
\end{align}
where $\rho_k = \frac{k!}{j_{1}!\ldots j_{M}!} $.

**Integrating a monomial**

The spherical integral of a monomial is discussed in detail in [2], but the main result gives,
\begin{align}
  \int_{S_n}\int_{S_n} \prod_{t=1}^M (L_{tt} y_t x_t)^{j_{t}}d\sigma_n d\sigma_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl} \left( 2\frac{\prod_{t=1}^M\Gamma(q_{t})}{\Gamma(\sum_{t=1}^M q_t)} \right)^2 \prod_{t=1}^M L_{tt}^{j_{t}} & : j_{t} \mbox{ all even} \\ 0& : \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right .\tag{5}
\end{align}

Where $q_{t} = \frac{1}{2} (j_{t} + 1)$. Putting (5) into (4) then gives,
\begin{align}
I =& 4 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!}\sum_{j_{1} + \ldots + j_{M} = k \\ \forall t \mod(j_{t},2) = 0 } \rho_k \left(\frac{\prod_{t=1}^M\Gamma(q_{t})}{\Gamma(\sum_{t=1}^M q_{t})} \right)^2 \prod_{t=1}^M L_{tt}^{j_{t}} \tag{6}
\end{align}

**Simplification**

Since the terms are non-zero only when all of the the $j_t$, and hence $k$, are even; after some cancellations, the sum can be written,
\begin{align}
I =& 4 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j_{1} + \ldots + j_{M} = k} \frac{n^{2k}}{\prod_{t=1}^M (2j_{t})!}\left(\frac{\prod_{t=1}^M\Gamma(j_{t} + \frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{M}{2} + \sum_{t=1}^M j_{t})} \right)^2 \prod_{t=1}^M L_{tt}^{2j_{t}} \\
 =& 4 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^{2k}}{\Gamma(\frac{M}{2} + k)^2} \sum_{j_{1} + \ldots + j_{M} = k}\prod_{t=1}^M \frac{\left(\Gamma(j_{t} + \frac{1}{2}) L_{tt}^{j_{t}}\right)^2}{ (2j_{t})!}\tag{7}
\end{align}

[1] *Baker, John A.*, [**Integration over spheres and the divergence theorem for balls**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2974821), Am. Math. Mon. 104, No. 1, 36-47 (1997). [ZBL0877.26008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0877.26008).

[2] *Folland, Gerald B.*, [**How to integrate a polynomial over a sphere**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2695802), Am. Math. Mon. 108, No. 5, 446-448 (2001). [ZBL1046.26503](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1046.26503).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very clear and detailed answer !